# IF results different from IFS result in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Using these two formulas in Google Sheets results in different output results.
The IF result will expand the array across the cells as expected.
The IFS result only displays the first array value.

```
=IF(1=1,{1,2,3}) RESULT: 1 2 3 (across three cells)
=IFS(1=1,{1,2,3}) RESULT: 1 (in one cell)
```

Can someone explain why these results differ?

Answer (score 1):

You may think that behaviour of **`IFS()`** is similar to **`IF()`** and reason of having **`IFS()`** is to avoid nesting of multiple **`IF()`** but that's not so true. Yes, there are some common baselines however, there is a major difference when it comes to arrays. **`IFS()`** in a combination of arrayed output expects arrayed input - that's why you got returned single-cell output instead of arrayed output.

- let's say your **`IF()`** formula is like:

  [image]
- "converting" it into **`IFS()`** will return this (because cell **A1** is not array/range):

  [image]
- now let's add a arrayformula (ranged input):

  [image]
- also note this behaviour:

  [image] [image]

Comment: I can appreciate that's "how it works" but the function description between the two doesn't distinguish that difference. As described....
Syntax
IFS(condition1, value1, [condition2, value2, …])

condition1 - The first condition to be evaluated. This can be a boolean, a number, an array, or a reference to any of those.

value1 - The returned value if condition1 is TRUE.

condition2, value2, … - Additional conditions and values if the first one is evaluated to be false.

Notes
If all conditions are FALSE, #N/A is returned.

Comment: more you will involve with formulas, you will realize how lame is google documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

Not at answer to *why* (IMO off topic) but to get the same result from IFS:

```
=IFS({1,1,1},{1,2,3})
```

Can be written:

```
=IFS({1=1,1=1,1=1},{1,2,3})
```

Comment: Got it... my challenge is the test in condition1 has nothing to do with the value1 information. In this case I'm forced to use nested IF statements to get the "right" results. Defies logic IMO.